# Jupyter notebook dark mode when downloaded as html does not render correctly

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, darkmode

I am using a dark theme in jupyter notebook and it is working fine in the browser. But when I download it as an HTML file it is not as expected, the background colour is light however the blocks have a dark colour.

Here is the image of [jupyter notebook when running in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jvue0.png)

and this is the output [of the notebook downloaded as html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hcmWM.png)

I want the downloaded HTML to be rendered the same way as the notebook is in browser

Comment: Please embed any images into your question and not a link to Imgur.

Comment: I am sorry, I am unable to embed the images in the question. If you click on the link it would open the image.

Answer (score 0):

From terminal you can do the following

```sh
jupyter nbconvert <notebook_name> --to html --HTMLExporter.theme=dark
```